# R populate data frame applying function taking parameters in multiple columns and rows

Tags: r, loops, dictionary, apply, sapply

I have a grid of blank values I'd like to fill using a function that takes multiple parameters in the given row as well as column.

Here is an example:

```
#make up var1 and var2 and join into data frame
var1 <- rnorm(500, 5, 2)
var2 <- rnorm(500, 20, 20)
df <- data.frame(var1, var2)

#define columns
x_values <- as.character(1:100)

#create columns of df and fill with NA
df[, x_values] <- NA

#define function that determines values in each cell
my_funct <- function(var1, var2, col){
  (var1^3 - var2^2)*col
}
```

My data looks like

```
       var1       var2  1  2  3  4  5  6
1 7.0570704  31.508049 NA NA NA NA NA NA
2 0.6965604  32.288748 NA NA NA NA NA NA
3 4.9869819   4.369592 NA NA NA NA NA NA
4 8.0933870  31.038571 NA NA NA NA NA NA
5 6.1667702  26.887448 NA NA NA NA NA NA
6 3.1476294 -10.806836 NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

For each given cell, `df[i, j]` of this data frame, I'd like to populate it with a the output from `my_funct`, which takes the inputs `df[i, 'var1']`, `df[i, 'var2']`, and the column name value (for which I could simply use j-2).

I wrote a nested loop that iterates over each row and column, but it was extremely slow. I'm guessing an apply or map function would be much more efficient. Any help?

Comment: It looks like your function already accepts vectors, so `my_funct(dat$var1, dat$var2, 1)` will return a vector the same length as the number of rows of your data.frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to iterate over columns without iterating over rows:

```
res <- sapply(1:100, function(i) {
  my_funct(df[, "var1"], df[, "var2"], i)
})
```

`sapply` returns a matrix where each column corresponds to `i`.